# Ionic Cordova windows 10 app with SalesforceMobileSDK

Tags: mobilesdk, cordova, salesforcesdk

I am creating a hybrid app for Windows 10 using Ionic, Cordova and SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin.

I followed below steps -

1. created ionic-cordova app: `ionic start helloWorld sidemenu --type=ionic-angular`
2. Added windows platform: `ionic cordova platform add windows`
3. Added Salesforce plugin: `ionic cordova plgin add https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin`
4. Added `bootconfig.json` and servers.xml in www/ folder
5. Install forcejs: `npm install forcejs`
6. Run `cordova prepare`
7. Opened `CordovaApp.sln` file in VS 2015 and built the solution.

When I run the app in VS 2015 after build, I am getting the homepage of the app instead of Salesforce connected app's login page.

I am not able find out if I missed any step here. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The Salesforce Mobile SDK does not windows.

To get a native Windows app you could use a solution such as [MobileCaddy](https://mobilecaddy.net) (full disclosure, I work for them), there may be other solutions also. Apps built with MobileCaddy mean x-platform support for Android/iOS/Windows with a single codebase.

Comment: Any official doc or proof for Salesforce Mobile SDK does not support windows?

Comment: Yes, In fact one of the maintainers actually replied to you on their github repo :)
https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin/issues/455#issuecomment-496571152